# JavaFx Webview doesn't load url

Tags: webview, javafx, load, jpanel

I followed a lot of tutorials, but maybe I'm missing something, because the url is not loaded in the javafx webview and a white panel is being displayed, instead of a webpage. I tried with http://google.com and other webpages, but neither one is being displayed. 
The JPanel from below appears in a JTabbedPane. I think the white panel is the JFXPanel, that is populated below.

This is the code:

```
public class RtcOverview extends JPanel {

private final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
private WebEngine engine;

String url = "http://google.com";

public RtcOverview() {

    super();
    initComponents();
    this.add(jfxPanel);
}

private void initComponents() {


    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            WebView view = new WebView();

            engine = view.getEngine();
            engine.load(url);
            Scene scene = new Scene(view);
            jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Runs perfectly for me. I am attaching a MCVE, so that you can compare and see what went wrong in your case. In case this MCVE fails on your machine, I would advice you to check with your internet settings and make sure that your settings doesn't block the application from using the internet.

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    private WebEngine engine;

    String url = "http://google.com";

    public Main() {
        super();
        initComponents();
        getContentPane().add(jfxPanel);
        setSize(500, 500);
        // Kill everything on closing the frame
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                WebView view = new WebView();
                engine = view.getEngine();
                engine.load(url);
                Scene scene = new Scene(view);
                jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my life, i was struggling so much and it seems, that the proxy was guilty, i had to add proxy with System.setProperty(). Thank you so much for your help!! Bless you man.